# compiling listing generated by visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, masm

I generated listing file for my visual studio project, and I want to change/add few assembly instructions and assemble it to working exe file, but I keep on receiving errors like:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line
>   Error   A2008   syntax error : .    main.asm    53  -> referring to __RTC_InitBase.rtc$IMZ DD FLAT:__RTC_InitBase

or unmatched blocks. is there any way to generate fully working masm source so I can assemble it with little mods?